# How to deploy React.js application that makes server calls to IIS?

Tags: reactjs, iis, server, hosting

Really new to web dev. so forgive me if this is a simple issue...

I want to host a React application on Microsoft IIS. This application makes server calls: this is the project I am trying to do https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-app-with-node-js-server-proxy)

What happens when I link the build to IIS is that I'm able to type something in the form, but I'm unable to see a response from the application (the fetch call is being made but is failing and nothing is returned). When I run `npm run dev` in the project folder the form works as it should, so it appears that the server isn't being hosted(?).

Comment: Are you definitely running the IIS server? Have you used something like Postman to test that your API endpoints are working ass expected?

Comment: Hey Luke, thanks for responding. I wasn't even aware of anything like Postman; I will have a look...

Answer (score -1):

to deploy react application in iis follow below steps:

1)run below command to build the site:

```
npm run build
```

the above command creates a build folder inside your application folder.

2)now open iis manager.right-click on the server node and select create new site.

provide site binding detailed and set the folder path of the site to the build folder which is generated by the command.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60110712/11147346

Comment: Hey Jalpa, thanks for responding. I've actually done this step by step, yet I'm unable to fetch any data. I believe my server.js file never runs (as per the link in my question). I get a failed fetch...any ideas?

Comment: @TrustLearning could you please share the snapshot fo the browser developer console

Comment: hey @Jalpa Panchal, sorry for the late response; heres whats happening. When I don't run the server on my machine (I'm really new to this but I run node server.js to start up the server on localhost:5000), the application that I have running IIS is able to fetch data as it can connect to the localhost:5000. However, when I stop running the local server, the status of my application's fetch requests is: (failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I'm unsure what the next step is, I was thinking I can upload the server on another IIS host.